Calculate query cost in BigQuery using Capcity compute pricing model
My company is using the Capacity compute pricing model by purchasing slots for BigQuery. I'm calculating the cost of each query so that everyone on my team can review their query performance. I checked the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS table using the total_slot_ms column with the formula: ROUND((total_slot_ms / 3600000) * hour_slot_price, 2), but this only accounts for about a quarter of the daily cost. However, using ROUND((total_bytes_billed / POW(10, 12)) * scan_bytes_price, 2) gives a number that is closer to the actual cost.
Do you have any idea? Should I continue using total_bytes_billed to calculate the cost of each query even though we are on Capacity compute pricing? Many thanks!
SELECT
  date(creation_time) as creation_date,
  job_id,
  user_email,
  creation_time,
  start_time,
  end_time,
  total_bytes_processed,
  total_bytes_billed,
  ROUND((total_bytes_billed / POW(10, 12)) * 6.25, 2) AS data_processed_cost_usd,
  total_slot_ms,
  ROUND((total_slot_ms / 3600000) * 0.0768, 2) AS slot_time_cost_usd,  
  SAFE_DIVIDE(total_slot_ms, TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_time, start_time, MILLISECOND)) AS avg_slots,
  query
FROM
  `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND job_type = 'QUERY'
  AND state = 'DONE'
  AND creation_time >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)  -- Last 7 days
ORDER BY
  total_cost_usd DESC


How many slots and queries do you have? (and how many slot ms (or hour) are consumed?)

Hi @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for your response. Sometimes we have to increase the number of slots due to a lack of resources to perform BigQuery activities, and the number of queries isn't fixed; it depends on the users and our monthly, daily, and hourly jobs. So, why do you want to know about that? Will I need to take them into the calculation?

In fact, there is a difference between the slots used and the slot billed. The slots are reserved by bulk of 100 (now 50 I think, not sure about the rollout of this optimisation). And you pay them at least for 1 minutes (especially when you use the slot autoscale.) Therefore according to the number of slots used and the average query duration, this difference can be minimized, or can be significant.

I got an answer from the Google team. I hope it’s helpful for anyone researching a similar issue:

The total_slot_ms metric, available in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS
table, is the most relevant measure of how many slots a query consumes
and should be the primary factor in cost calculations. To determine
the cost per query, use the formula:
Cost Per Query = (total_slot_ms/ 3600000)× hour_slot_price
This formula directly correlates the time slots are in use with your
committed costs. If you find that the sum of these calculated costs
does not match the total daily costs, it could be due to idle slot
time or other system overheads not directly attributed to specific
queries.
While total_bytes_billed is traditionally used in On-Demand pricing
models, where costs are based on data processed, it can still serve as
a supplementary metric under Capacity pricing. It helps assess query
efficiency by comparing data processed against slot usage. A query
that processes large amounts of data but consumes fewer slots might
indicate efficient usage, even under Capacity pricing.
However, the most critical aspect of managing costs under this pricing
model is optimizing slot utilization. Unused slots still contribute to
the overall costs, so maximizing their usage across queries is
essential. Tools like BigQuery's reservation management can help in
better allocating slots across teams or projects, ensuring that your
committed resources are fully utilized.

